# How do I select text from one field that is actually text from one table, and insert the corresponding number into another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a drop down list that I populate from one table that I need to use the selected value in the drop down list to insert into another field in another table. The field that I use to populate the DDL is text and table it pulls from has a numeric PK. How do I insert that PK as an FK in the other table? Here is the code:

Markup:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Docs] WHERE [ID] = ?" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Docs] ([Filename], [Label], [Section]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Docs]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Docs] SET [Filename] = ?, [Label] = ?, [Section] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Filename" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Label" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Section" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Filename" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Label" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Section" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Sections]">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<h2>Add a document</h2><br />
<asp:FormView ID="Formview1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert">

    <InsertItemTemplate>
        Label:
        <asp:TextBox ID="LabelTextBox" runat="server" />
        <br />
        Section:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSection" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="AccessDatasource2" DataTextField="Sections" DataValueField="Sections" />
        <br /><br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload document" OnClick="UploadFile" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="UploadStatusLabel" runat="server" Text="Upload Status: " />
    </InsertItemTemplate>

</asp:FormView>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtDocLabelText = (TextBox)Formview1.FindControl("LabelTextBox");
    DropDownList ddlSection = (DropDownList)Formview1.FindControl("ddlSection");
    FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)Formview1.FindControl("FileUpload1");
    Label UploadStatusLabel = (Label)Formview1.FindControl("UploadStatusLabel");

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/doc" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "appl/text" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.msword" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-word" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/winword" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/word" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/msword" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/x-msw6" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/x-msword" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/pdf" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/x-pdf" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template"
                )
            {
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength < 102400000)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    string section = ddlSection.SelectedValue;
                    string label = txtDocLabelText.Text;
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/docs/HRDocs") + filename);
                    UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Complete!";
                    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\webvideos.mdb;";
                    string cmdstr = "INSERT INTO [Docs] ([Filename], [Label], [Section]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

                    con.Open();
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Filename", filename);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Label", label);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", section);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    Response.Redirect("ManageHRDocs.aspx");
                }
                else
                    UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 100 MB!";
            }
            else
                UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Not an accepted file type";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

What is the best way to do this? I should also add that the code as it is currently returns a data mismatch because what is selected for the drop down list is text and the "section" field in the Docs table is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the DataValueField to the primary key retrieved through the query used by your AccessDataSource that populates the dropdownlist. The DataTextField can stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by adding a switch statment, as follows:

```
switch (section)
    {
        case "Benefits - Open Enrollment":
            sectionNumber = 1;
            break;
        case "Benefits - Summaries":
            sectionNumber = 2;
            break;
        case "Benefits - 401(k)":
            sectionNumber = 3;
            break;
        case "Benefits - HSA/FSA":
            sectionNumber = 4;
            break;
        case "Forms - Tax/Payroll":
            sectionNumber = 5;
            break;
    }
```

That was quite fun. I'm still open to other answers as well! And since it is a drop down list that I'm doing this for, I didn't bother with a default case because it is not possible to select a blank or null value.